# Angular or JavaScript to format/beautify JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to format this json in angular this is the result from extending all models from multiple forms.

```
{
"identifications": {}, 
"insurances": [
{
  "insurances": [
    {
      "category": "",
      "compName": "",
      "planType": "",
      "note": ""
    }
  ]
}
],
"medical": {
   "doctors": [
    {
       "doctors": [
      {
        "firstname": "James"
        "note": "James Bond Note"
      },
      {
        "firstname": "Robin",
        "note": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor"
      }
    ]
  }
], 
"records": {}
}
```

Here's I need to achieve to insert it into the API.

```
    {
        "parent_id": 17,    
        "insurances": [{
            "insurance_type": "",
            "notes": ""
        }],
        "medical": { 
            "doctors": {},
            "blood": {},
        },
        "records": {}
    }
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to beautify json?

Comment: I don't feel that it's readily apparent what you need done. If you need to filter or translate original JSON to another format, just parse the JSON into an object, then map the facets of the original object into a new object using your own rules.

Comment: @PatrickEvans cause of this.

"medical": {
   "doctors": [
    {
       "doctors": [

I want it to be this way.
"medical": { 
            "doctors": {},

Comment: that is not beautifying, beautifying makes it so you can display it in a readable fashion. You are wanting to change the structure

Comment: You can build your own custom JSON object to send back to your API. With plain old javascript or you can alter whatever is giving you that response to return what you need.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Whatever it is.I'd guess you can't get my question.Hard to explain since there's a limitation how I post my question here in SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking at just pretty-printing stuff, investigate JSON.stringify:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

If you're trying to change the object from one data representation to another (I'll note that the second object is structurally different from the first, not just a matter of whitespace), then you just need to write some javascript that does stuff like `new.doctors = old[0].medical[1].doctors` (example, not actual code)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but nowadays you should use the `json` [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json). For example:

```
var data = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

Then in the template:

```
{{ data|json:2 }}
```

Should output

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```